# How to use the Mean Value Theorem to "establish bounds"?

Tags: calculus, analysis, mean-value-theorem

I am faced with the following question:

> Use the mean value theorem to establish bounds in the following cases.
>
> (a) For $-\ln(1-y)$, by considering $\ln x$ in the range $0<1-y<x<1$.
>
> (b) For $e^y-1$, by considering $e^x-1$ in the range $0<x<y$.

I understand the definition of the Mean Value Theorem — my problem is I do not understand what the question is asking!

What are we trying to "establish bounds" for? For the values of the functions (e.g. $-\ln(1-y)$)? Or for the values of the derivatives? And what do they mean by "considering [another function]"? And isn't e.g. $0<x<y$ the domain of the functions, not their range?

Maybe I am missing something obvious. You can provide solutions if you wish, but mostly I am looking for insights into understanding the question.

(The question is exercise 2.26 in *Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering*, by Riley, Hobson, and Bence.)

Comment: Have you tried writing out what the MVT tells you when applied to $\ln x$ on the interval $(1-y, 1)$?  This should give you a statement about $-\ln (1-y)$ in terms of $1/c$ (the derivative of $\ln x$ evaluated at some point $c$ in the interval) which you can then use to determine an upper and lower bound for $-\ln (1-y)$.

Comment: @TMGallagher I see what you mean. It was easier than I expected. In the simplicity of the exercise question I overcomplicated the terminology. If you post your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it. :)